# Convert JSON tree data to nodes and links

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Good Day,

i like to know how to convert tree data from flare.json into nodes and links?
many thanks in advance, also i´m not using a tree visualization i need it for an Force-directed graph

from

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good Day .. the solution for me is very simple.. let´s tweak the d3:

checked on : http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

[image]